# Jquery multiply currency with symbols

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a ticket ordering form that uses an input field that is controlled by a minus(-1) and plus(+1) button.

There is another script that calculates the total of the order by taking the (price) of each ticket (.qty-holder) and multiplying it by the (quantity) inside of the input.

The price is generated by PHP and is echoed with an '$#36;' ($) before the number is printed. This causes the javascript calculation to only be a NaN. I cannot get the value calculated when the $ sign is in there, it only works if it's just a number.

Is there a way to make the script search for the numbers only inside of a tag, and how would I make it so the output(total) contains a '$' and a number that has two decimal places?

Also, the minus and plus buttons script does not effect the value that is calculated. So if I click the plus button to increase the number in the input, a new total is not calculated. Is there a way to connect those two, and make the max value from the plus button 5?

My code is below. Any help is much appreciated!

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>
<div class='qty-holder'>
  <a class='minus increment qty value-btn' href='#'>-</a>
  <input type='number' name='quantity_37' class='value qty' id='37' step='1' min='0' max='5' value='0' readonly> 
  <a class='plus increment qty value-btn' href='#'>+</a>
  <span class='hidden fees'>&#36;1.60</span>
  <span class='hidden price'>&#36;20.00</span> 
  <span class='hidden sum'>0</span>       
</div>
</div>
</div>              
<div class="checkout">
  <span>Fees:</span><span class="fees pull-right"></span><br />
  <span>Total:</span><span id="total" class="pull-right"></span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger text-uppercase btn-tickets">Checkout</button>
</div>


<script>  
   $(function(){
     $('.increment').click(function() {
        var valueElement = $('#'+$(this).siblings('input').attr('id'));
        if($(this).hasClass('plus')) 
        { valueElement.val(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.val()) + 1)); } 
        else if (valueElement.val() > 0) // Stops the value going into negatives
        { valueElement.val(Math.max(parseInt(valueElement.val()) - 1)); } 
     return false;
  });
});
</script> 
<script>
function getTotal(){
    var total = 0.00;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();

$('.value').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.qty-holder');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
</script>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calculating? Do you use that hidden field or input type text for calculating?

Comment: The <input> field is the qty (.value mentioned in the js) and that's multiplied by the price. The class 'hidden' is just so nothing shows up on the actual page.

Comment: Its simple logic, use `split` to split using `&#36;` as string using which we want splitted text . And now take 1st index(remember it starts from 0th index) in a variable and do further calculation